Change value of dropdown from another dropdown in Angular 17
I'm trying to setup the form in such a way that when someone selects Mr in the first dropdown, the value changes to male in the second dropdown.
Likewise, if someone chooses Miss/Mrs, the 2nd dropdown changes to female.
How can I achieve this?
Here is the HTML
<div class="master">
  <select [(ngModel)]="registration.salutation">
    <option value="Mr">Mr &nbsp;</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="slave">
  <select [(ngModel)]="registration.gender">
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
    <option value="others">Others</option>
  </select>
</div>

This is the .TS:
ngOnInit(): void {
  //this.registration.salutation = 'Mr';
  if(this.registration.salutation = 'Mr') {
    this.registration.gender = 'male';
  }
  if(this.registration.salutation = 'Mrs' || 'Miss') {
    this.registration.gender = 'female';
  }
}

Currently, nothing happens when I choose any value in the first dropdown.

You can use the ngModelChange event to apply your logic:
<div class="master">
  <select [(ngModel)]="registration.salutation" (ngModelChange)="salutationChange()">
    <option value="Mr">Mr &nbsp;</option>
    <option value="Miss">Miss</option>
    <option value="Mrs">Mrs</option>
    <option value="Dr">Dr</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
  </select>
</div>

salutationChange() {
  if (this.registration.salutation === 'Mr') {
    this.registration.gender = 'male';
  } else if (this.registration.salutation === 'Mrs' || 'Miss') {
    this.registration.gender = 'female';
  }
}


Amazing! Still learning Angular. Thank you so much.  Will accept your answer in 4 minutes :)
Btw, == works instead of = like this: if(this.registration.salutation == 'Mr') {

@ElaineByene Thanks for the hint, will update my answer. It is also wrong in the question ;)

Yes yes. Still learning Angular :)
